PHPで異体字判定することはできますか？
PHPかJavsaScriptで異体字判定することはできますか？
疑問に思ったきっかけ
API経由でXへ投稿したら、ハッシュタグに異体字が含まれていたらしく、正常に機能しませんでした。
やりたいこと
文字列を操作する際、異体字があるかどうか事前に判定したい。可能なら、異体字ではない文字へ変換したい

Twitterのハッシュタグにどのようなコードポイントが使えるかの詳細な仕様は見つけられませんでした。
記号はダメというルールだそうですが、もしかしたら異体字セレクタなどの制御コードもダメなのかもしれないと推測できます。Unicode の L カテゴリだけ受け付ける仕様かもしれません。

X (旧 Twitter) における異体字の定義と
我々がここで議論する異体字の定義と
が違うと、この場でどんな議論しても X に投稿できないであろう事態は変わりません。もっと言うと「異体字が原因で投稿が拒否された」ということが確定しているのであれば話を続けることに意味があるのでしょうが、そうでないなら不確定情報ですから労力の無駄に終わりかねません。
なので実践的な答えは「 X (旧 Twitter) に問い合わせてください」となるでしょう。どこに尋ねればよいのかとか、そもそも答えが返ってくるかどうかわからないとか、その辺はまた別問題ってことで。
